# How do I specify a port number dynamically for an HTTPUrl?

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

I have a project that I am working on. It comes in two parts. For this part, we are supposed to be building the server, client communicator, and other functionality. We are not building the client yet; in order to pass off this part of the project, there is an automated tester that will act as the client. It will specify a random port number and create the server, then call a bunch of methods through the communicator.

The only place that I have access to the port number is when I initialize the server. The server itself has a main method that sets up the server; I have tried storing it as a static variable to access later, but when I try to access it I always get 0 as the port number in the request, which is wrong.

This line is from the ClientCommunicator. Specifically, this is what happens when the "client" calls the validateUser function, which only accepts two arguments: username and password. I cannot pass the port number as an additional argument.

```
String response = HttpClientHelper.doGetRequest(Helper.BASE_URL +"validateUser?username="+username+"&password="+password,null);
```

Helper has a static final variable BASE_URL which is currently set to

```
public static final BASE_URL = "http://localhost:8080/";
```

Obviously, this is no longer going to work.
The change I would like to make would be to turn the line in my client communicator to

```
String response = ...(Helper.BASE_URL + (PORT_NUMBER) + "/" +...
```

where PORT_NUMBER would actually be something like Server.PORT_NUMBER,

and turn BASE_URL to

```
public static final BASE_URL = "http://localhost:"
```

However, I'm not sure how I would dynamically add the port number into the doGetRequest. I have tried storing it as a static variable in the server class which gets initialized when the server is started, but if I try to access it that way it ends up defaulting to 0.

My server class (I am not type-checking in this class for the port number, it's done elsewhere):

```
public class IndexerServer{
    public static int port;

    public enum RequestMethod {
        GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS, TRACE
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int port = 8080;
        if(args.length > 0){
            port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        }
        IndexerServer.port = port;
        InetSocketAddress addr = new InetSocketAddress(port);
        HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(addr,0);
        Helper.BASE_URL+= port + "/";

        server.createContext("/validateUser",new ValidateUser());
        server.createContext("/getProjects",new GetProjects());
        server.createContext("/getSampleImage",new GetSampleImage());
        server.createContext("/downloadBatch",new DownloadBatch());
        server.createContext("/getFields",new GetFields());
        server.createContext("/search",new Search());
        server.createContext("/submitbatch",new SubmitBatch());

        server.createContext("/images",new ImageDownloader());
        server.createContext("/fieldhelp",new HtmlDownloader());
        server.createContext("/knowndata",new HtmlDownloader());

        server.setExecutor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool());
        server.start();
        System.out.println("Server is listening on port "+port);
    }
}
```

and the pertinent part of the HTTPHelper

```
public class HttpClientHelper
{
public static String doGetRequest(String urlString,Map<String,String> headers){
    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    try {
        //Create connection
        url = new URL(urlString);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");

        connection.setUseCaches (false);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);

        if(connection.getResponseCode() == 500){
            return "failed";
        }
        //Get Response
        InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
        while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(line);
        }
        rd.close();
        return response.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;

    } finally {

        if(connection != null) {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about losing the authority or anchor part of the input URL, you can just parse it, break it up and recreate it, replacing the port:

```
final int PORT = 42;

URL url = new URL(str);
URL newurl = new URL(url.getProtocol(), url.getHost(), PORT, url.getFile());
```

For example, for the input:

```
http://user:pass@hello.com:1234/path/file.ext?param=value#anchor
```

The output is:

```
http://hello.com:42/path/file.ext?param=value
```

If you want to preserve the authority / anchor, you'll have to modify the host and output appropriately (`url.getAuthority()` and `url.getRef()` will return the parsed components).

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. I need a way to put the correct port number in the line before the URL is ever called. Actually, I suppose I could create a new URL, but the problem is the same: How do I get that 42 to be whatever the random port number is?

Comment: @JoshuaZollinger Replace 42 with a variable that contains the port number (I edited to show this...), and call `newurl.openConnection()`...

Comment: Where would I store that variable? The client initializes the server with a random port number. The server has a main class that initializes an HttpServer with the specified port. I have tried storing that port number into a static variable, but when I call the static variable later (just like you suggested), it's defaulting to 0 every time.

Comment: Huh? What do you mean the "client initializes the server"? Are your client and server in the same program? Unfortunately, you will need to clarify your question, because as it stands, it's hard to tell exactly what you're trying to accomplish here. A "client" makes HTTP requests to a remote "server"; if you are using the words "client" and "server" with non-traditional meanings, you will have to clarify.

Comment: I have updated the question. Hopefully it's a little more clear. And sorry for the trouble; I am in over my head atm.

Answer (score 0):

Are the server and client communicator two different programs? If so, you can simply pass the port as an extra argument to the client when starting up and compose the string from there.

If both classes are part of the same program you can simply pass the port to `HttpClientHelper` using `Integer.toString(port)` when you call this helper. Something along the lines of `url = new URL(urlString + port)`.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is the client that has to pass the port to the server. I know, it's bass ackwards. And I can't pass the port number as an argument from the client; input and outputs are fixed by the project designer (it's an automated passoff)

Comment: @JoshuaZollinger What you're asking is starting to make less and less sense. You can't tell the server what port you want it to run HTTP services on via HTTP, unless you already have an HTTP server running on a known port. You need to clarify your question, because "how do I specify a port number dynamically for an HTTP URL" does not actually seem to be your question.

Comment: @JoshuaZollinger This is not clear at all from the question. You should update it with the exact details and constrains.

Comment: I did a terrible job explaining. I might need to change the question title. The automated tester will will choose a random port number and initialize the server with that port number. I do not have access to that tester, only the server, so I cannot just grab it there. I tried storing it into a static variable when I initialize the server, but when I try to access it later it is 0.